# if .isin() dataframe one, check condition in dataframe 2, append new dataframe with checked conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

i have two dataframes

df1 has a list of ids and dates

| id | e1 | e2 | e3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-09-12 | 2001-03-06 | 1999-09-03 |
| 2 | 2009-09-07 | 2002-04-06 | 2003-01-02 |
| 3 | 2005-08-09 | 2005-06-04 | 2008-01-02 |

df2 has the same ids, and other values

| id | e1 | e2 | e3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A120 | B130 | C122 |
| 2 | BD43 | A200 | A111 |
| 3 | C890 | B123 | A190 |

I want to iterate through df2, look for values that start with 'A' (for example (A120, A200..etc) in each column, once I find the value, I will go to df1 in the same rowxcolumn and see if the date is >= 2005-01-01, and add all the ids that checks those two conditions to a new dataframe.

so the ideal results would be something like this:

| id | e1 | e2 | e3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A120 | B130 | C112 |
| 3 | C890 | B123 | A190 |

the only way I could manage was a for loop looping through both matrices, but it is very slow since the dataframes are very large. is there a different approach to this problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use boolean indexing:

```
ref = '2005-01-01'

# is the date < ref?
m1 = df1.set_index('id').le(ref)
# is the string starting with A?
m2 = df2.set_index('id').apply(lambda s: s.str.startswith('A'))

# if both conditions are matched anywhere in the row, drop it
out = df1[~(m1&m2).any(axis=1).to_numpy()]
```

*NB. if `id` is the index, don't perform the `set_index('id')` step.*
Output:

```
   id          e1          e2          e3
0   1  2012-09-12  2001-03-06  1999-09-03
2   3  2005-08-09  2005-06-04  2008-01-02
```

Comment: thank you, i run the code and it gave TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=int64 and str.

Comment: Can you provide reproducible constructors for you input DataFrames?

Comment: Also, try `m1 = df1.filter(regex=r'e\d+').le(ref) ; m2 = df2.filter(regex=r'e\d+').apply(lambda s: s.str.startswith('A'))`

Comment: the second code yielded this error: ValueError: Item wrong length 3090 instead of 1546.
1546 is the length of my dataframes each
also, sorry what do you mean by reproducible constructors?